# How can I get a notification when a window becomes full-screen in Swift?

Tags: swift, macos, fullscreen

I want to add a full-screen mode setting to my game. However, I need to automatically update the setting if the user manually toggles full-screen mode.

How do I run code as soon as fullscreen is toggled by any means? In other words, how can I receive a notification when the user clicks the green button at the top of the window to make it full-screen?

Without this information, I cannot figure out how to synchronize my application's full-screen mode setting with the UI provided by the operating system.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the code from the other answer, I was able to construct the code to do this:

In applicationDidFinishLaunching:

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: NSWindow.willEnterFullScreenNotification, object: nil, queue: OperationQueue.main, using: { note in
    print("Entered Fullscreen")
})

NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: NSWindow.willExitFullScreenNotification, object: nil, queue: OperationQueue.main, using: { note in
    print("Exited Fullscreen")
})
```

Answer (score 4):

You just need to await for a notification from `NSWindow`

```
import SwiftUI
import Combine

struct SampleView: View {
    var cancellabel : AnyCancellable?
        init(){
            cancellabel = NotificationCenter.default.publisher(for: NSWindow.willEnterFullScreenNotification).sink { (notification) in
        print(notification.object)
    }

    var body: some View {

    }
}
```

Comment: Do I need the Combine library? Are you sure this does the task in the minimum amount of code possible?

Comment: Even though _this_ code is useless to me, with it I was able to construct code that I could use

Comment: Combine is built in as SwiftUI in Xcode. It’s a mindset changer framework.